# Finding a input string in list with Python

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to use input to find a string in my list. The current output in Python when I type 'sum'(without quotations) is 'Sorry, that isn't available yet.'

When I input 'sum' with the quotations it comes back as 'Okay, great! We can do that.'

How would I make it so the user doesn't have to input the string with quotations?

```
list = ['average','sum','count','store','DC']
search = input("What would you like to find in the data?")
search = str(search)

if search in list:
    print("Okay, great! We can do that.")
else:
    print("Sorry, that isn't available yet.")
```

Comment: you might wanna re check that, inputting `sum` definitely works, as it should

Comment: It seems like your code needs to work properly. Is this all your relevant part of your code?

Comment: I agree it should be working. I'm wondering if it's the Atom package I am using that's causing the issue.

Comment: i tried your code on online editor and its woking perfectly, don't know where is the prblm? hint: **input** method always return **string** 

Comment: Just to make sure: You are not using Python 2, where `input` evaluates the input and thus `str(search)` might be `'<built-in function sum>'`? What does `print(search)` show? Does it work for the other values?

Answer (score 0):

Use string slicing while taking the input to get your desired output.

```
list = ['average','sum','count','store','DC']
search = input("What would you like to find in the data?")[1:-1]
search = str(search)

if search in list:
    print("Okay, great! We can do that.")
else:
    print("Sorry, that isn't available yet.")
```